# Temporarily close my account

Tags: discussion, support, behavior

I need to know if I can temporarily disable my account. I ran into a problem (minutes ago) where a user threatened me because I told them Stack Overflow was not a code service.
 I also changed my name and can now unfortunately not change it back. How can I best solve these issues?

Comment: If you had personally identifiable information in your profile in the past, closing your account **now** shouldn't help you much, right? I hope you immediately flagged those comments.

Comment: I flagged them but OP seemed to be stalking me and even after the comments were deleted, they somehow found me with my new alias.

Comment: If you interacted with one user, "finding" them again even when they change their nickname is trivial. Your user-id didn't change, and links to your account will still work. I sympathize with your situation, but closing your account wont do you much good. Closing **their** account would probably help a bit.

Comment: They can find your account via their browser history I imagine, changing your name doesn't change your id.

Comment: If you feel threatened raise a custom mod flag and explain exactly why that is so. You can always flag one of your own posts if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, I initially raised a flag simply requesting for removal of all the comments which was done but immediately OP kept mentioning me in their comments. I replied and deleted my comments and theirs somehow also disappeared. I've changed almost everything but that's annoying. I now have to post here under a false name up to at least Mar. Oh no!

Comment: If something rose to the level of "threatening", I hope the flags you used were descriptive of the situation. At the very least rude/abusive (which I think have  a higher priority in the mod queue), and/or a custom flag explaining the situation.

Comment: I did but was unfortunately mostly focused on my name. OP can unfortunately still find me by a Google search if they wanted to. Anyways, I'll stay off the site for a while and hopefully they forget all about me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Incognito_R but why are you afraid from this user, what can he do to you inside the internet *virtual* space? simply ignore him and continue your *virtual life*?

Comment: And with sede we have to wait a till Sunday for `select * from users where id = [ID]` to return your new data. I have heard that people where calling wellknow SO user at his company to get to them. People can be scary.

Comment: I’m sorry you were feeling threatened. If it is any help: all they did was post your public user link in a comment on the same post, perhaps as a misplaced attempt to ping you (like `@username` would do). I do note that that same user also apologised to you, I have the impression they really did not mean to come across as threatening.

Comment: You may not realise as the comments have been deleted. The person you had issues with has apologised, more than once. It seems like a simple misunderstanding

Comment: it's so easy to create misunderstandings with written comments anyway. I've stopped joking with Yvette for instance :)

Comment: On a completely different note, you should learn how to ignore trolls. There will always be people trolling and do not pay too much attention to them. Also, get into habit of not oversharing. There is no need to put your real name, address and social security number in the public profile on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Im not a fan of "Ignore trolls". The evidence to date is, it doesn't work. You *should* fight back, but smartly. Don't reply, report.  But don't get too concerned about danger. Trust me, as a former journalist, I've had some pretty savage threats before, things that have led to cops parking cars out the front of my house for weeks on end (Writing news reports on Neo Nazis can have unwelcome repercussions, alas). These people *never* carry through.

Comment: @NelsonGon _"...and theirs somehow also disappeared"_. I remember flagging the mentioned comment as "unfriendly or unkind" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54765003/6574038), a moderator may have deleted it. To my taste, the user is still acting strangely by requesting personal help from certain users.

Comment: @jay.sf Interestingly, I've seen they've mentioned me by linking to my account again! Maybe it's a case of not knowing how the site works.

Comment: @NelsonGon Maybe you're right and he's just not really familiar with the site, though I'm skeptical.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well it seams you haven't yet :P

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can change your name once per month. This is to prevent people from changing their names all the time. (That was a thing in the early days of Stack Overflow.)

You can't temporarily disable your account. You *could* delete it entirely, but quite frankly I hope you won't. Because that's giving in. Besides, if there was personally identifiable information in your account, that person may still follow you on other media.

You flagged the thing for moderator attention, and that is the appropriate thing to do. Let the moderators sort it out.

Don't let it get to you. Just keep going. If you see a good, well-researched question and know the answer... just post it. It may just make the asker's day. Don't let a single unpleasant person spoil that.

Comment: "(That was a thing in the early days of Stack Overflow.)" (It still is)

Comment: @Welbog You were the one that made them develop the policy, weren't you? Nice to meet you!

Comment: Related: *[Changing your display name on a whim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518)*

Answer (score 30):

The reason for the restriction on name changes was to alleviate the widespread confusion that S.L Barth mentioned. People were being quite whimsical about it, and that created some interesting problems.

If the need to change your name back isn't simply remorse for horsing around a bit too much, we'll generally do it for you (mods can also do this, but some would rather not take on the responsibility of editing anything in a user's profile). Since the change was due to something that unfortunately escalated to a bad place quickly, [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and request that it be changed.

**You must be very specific about what you want the name to be.** And, our input is checked against the same filters that everyone else has to live with, so trying to slide something in that way isn't recommended ;) But we don't want you going about with a name you don't like just because something got a bit out of hand. In other words, if the request isn't due to shenanigans, we're likely to be sympathetic.

You're also free to follow up with us directly concerning any kind of threat or abuse. The moderators *will* get to it timely, and they very often do escalate blatant or egregious cases to us for further review, but they won't be at all offended if you contact us simultaneously. If they've already taken action we'll be able to see their notes, and if they haven't, they'll be able to see our annotations and such.

While we can sometimes come off as insensitive clods when trying to guide new users, there's positively *no* excuse for threatening language or abusive behavior, and we take reports of it quite seriously.

Comment: Heh... was just about to post a comment on the Q: *I don't see anything threatening going on there... Looks like a couple of people just misunderstood/misread what they were saying to each other on the 'net. If you don't want to stick with this name for a month, then we can revert it to your previous name or a new name that'd you'd like (as long as it meets site policy) - you can either post a comment here (as the name will go public anyway at some point and this post links back to your account) or raise a custom flag on your own post linking to this post and what name you'd like.*

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I indeed would like to revert back to my old name(NelsonGon).

Comment: @NelsonGon done :)

Comment: What’s this, moderators with qualms about pushing buttons? Surely this cannot be true. It does not sound at all like us.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for caring. Thanks for caring about the data leak too.