# Why was flag declined though it actually helped to solve a situation?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, comment-flags

Today I came across [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380360/6574038). I remembered just yesterday raising a flag at a seemingly rude remark on [a question of the addressed user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54765003/r-codes-for-svm-to-forecast-monthly-uni-variate-data), the flag was considered as *helpful*. Taking another look there I noticed that two new weird comments of the OP have appeared. IMO this was a **clear** situation for moderator intervention to me and I flagged it as such. I received a reasonable comment, the flag was *declined*, though.

I've been specific in my flag comment and also linked to the meta thread above. I expressed that the OP is *probably* bullying and should *probably* be warned, but that is a moderator's decision not mine. As can be seen, I'm happy my flag did actually help, since the moderator has taken action and explained to the OP that we are not personally contacting other users on Stack Overflow to get help (which I actually find much better than my original suggestion).

Anyway, my intention was to help a probably bullied user with over 2.5k reputation, and without my flag probably no action would have been taken, but it was *declined*.

**My question is twofold:** What what shall I make of the declination, shouldn't I have flagged a difficult and unclear situation like this? Should I beware of the word *probably* in flag comments?

Comment: Because your assessment of the situation was incorrect. While there, I cleaned up the comments, as they had no value.

Comment: And did you not read the custom flag decline I used? That user is merely misunderstanding how you ping someone in comments. Copying and pasting a public profile URL is not bullying or threatening.

Comment: And if we felt the need to contact that specific user, we would already have done so on the basis of the previous flags that also led to that Meta post you link to. There was no need to flag the situation again. Several moderators have commented on that other post as well, so it should have been clear we were already aware of the situation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your comment. Get me right, I want to learn from this situation. Sure, you've assessed what's best to do,  and I drew your attention to it. I'd like to know what was actually was wrong with the flag as a whole?

Comment: Your flag felt redundant and showed that you read way more in those comments than was warranted, which is the main reason I declined the flags. In the meta post discussion, we already stated that the user was just trying to ping people.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, I admit my assessment was wrong but I felt that something had to be done. Ok I'm good with it, thanks for clarification, cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You flagged two comments that read roughly like this:

> stackoverflow.com/users/[userid1]/[name-part-of-url] i want your help please.
>
> isn't good enough no one yet replied me. stackoverflow.com/[userid2]/[name-part-of-url]

Those were completely harmless comments, in part because they don't actually ping anyone.

Even if they had correctly used `@username` pings, there was no evidence that that user was *abusing* pinging. Pinging two separate users, once, is not yet abusive.

Your flag read:

> I already flagged a comment of this user yesterday. The user keeps on acting strangely by demanding personal help from certain users and probably bullying. There's already a thread open on meta: meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380360/6574038. The user recently added two new comments with links to personal profiles. Probably this user should be warned.

I declined the flag, because trying to ping users by copying the public profile URL is not bullying, and the tone of the comments was not demanding.

I explained this in my decline reason:

> No, someone not yet understanding how the platform works and posting a few too many comments is not bullying. They are merely trying to ping someone to see if they can get help.

The term *probably* is also incorrect here. I'd use the term *perhaps* or *maybe* and add a question mark to the sentence. Using *probably* comes across to me that you would be very unhappy indeed if we didn't follow your advice to us there!

And perhaps you missed this, but I responded to that Meta post in the comments, as did another moderator, explaining to the user that there was just a simple misunderstanding:

> I’m sorry you were feeling threatened. If it is any help: all they did was post your public user link in a comment on the same post, perhaps as a misplaced attempt to ping you (like @username would do). I do note that that same user also apologised to you, I have the impression they really did not mean to come across as threatening. – Martijn Pieters♦
>
> You may not realise as the comments have been deleted. The person you had issues with has apologised, more than once. It seems like a simple misunderstanding – Yvette Colomb♦

Because you linked to that post, I assumed that you had, in fact, seen those comments, which made me feel your flag was misplaced.

In future, just flag comments such as these as 'no longer needed', unless there is more evidence that the user is (correctly) using pings excessively.

Comment: By the way, as I see it, "probably" and "maybe" are much more synonyms in German than in English, I'll keep that in mind!